# Clear Autofilter in Excel using C#

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, filter

I am exporting data from my WPF application to Excel successfully. In that Excel sheet I am filtering two columns at "AM" and "AL" . When I am going to reload the excel sheet the new filter values are conflicted with old filtered values.

I want to clear that two columns autofilter values. So can anybody give some suggestion about this problem and let me know how shall I proceed for this problem or send me some sample code for clear Autofilters for specific columns in Excel.

Here MyCode is

```
if (_taskPaneViewModel.TTLrecQtySelectionStart == _taskPaneViewModel.TTLrecQtyMinimum )
{
    range.AutoFilter(TTLrecQtyColumnNumber, Type.Missing, XlAutoFilterOperator.xlAnd,        Type.Missing, true);
}
```

Now I want to clear this autofilter in this range. Can ANYONE tell me the solution of this problem? It's breaking my head.

Comment: @Juliuze: Thanks for your reply. but there is no property name like AutoFilterMode available in range of values

Answer (score 0):

```
range.WorkSheet.AutoFilterMode = false;
```

Put the above statement before setting the filter using new columns.
Does that help?